# Get Tuesday's date for current week using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to obtain the current weeks date for Tuesday.

So for instance today is Thursday 06.04.2017 so the tuesday of this week would be 04.04.2017.

I am trying to do this using the below:

```
Dim iWeekday As Integer
iWeekday = Weekday(Now(), vbTuesday)
MsgBox iWeekday
```

but this is returning monday's date 03.04.2017

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: you need to use the result as a number to subtract, so if the result is 2, this means wednesday, so remove (2-1) to give the date.  `date-Weekday(Now(), vbTuesday)`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks but this produces a overflow error

Comment: i get `? now-Weekday(Now(), vbTuesday)`=03/04/2017 12:48:23 and ? `date-Weekday(Now(), vbTuesday)`=03/04/2017

Comment: @Nathan_Sav ok i did what you said, i accidentally defined iWeek as interger so i removed this. But now i get 03/04/2017. This is monday's date not Tuesdays :(

Comment: yes, note that i have -1 in my original answer.  Could you not put the effort in yourself for that one ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav well yes but surely this is a bit of a 'bodge job'. Why is it returning the incorrect value?

Comment: read about weekday, it shows the weekday, so if you want the calc to work, you use monday, or -1, its not a bodge job.  Did you expect a FirstTuesday, FirstWednesday function????

Comment: @Nathan_Sav you should perhaps learn to be less sensitive when someone asks you a question. And a down vote is not necessary for when a user asks a simple question.

Comment: I don't get sensitive on being asked a question, I do when the o/p puts in 0 effort and then calls work a "bodge job"  The down vote was for 0 effort, not for the question.  If you read the first search result from your question on google, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh134613(v=office.14).aspx, it shows you 2/3 of the way down how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't neeed to use `Now()` , `Date` is enough to get the current date (without time).

Try the code below:

```
Dim iWeekday As Date

iWeekday = Date - Weekday(Date, vbTuesday) + 1
MsgBox iWeekday
```